# Does the Spring-Flex 1.5 Sample work?

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, maven-2, blazeds

The samples and documentation in question can be found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.0.M1/

The reference doc ( [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.0.M1/reference/html/#samples) ) tells us to download the sample application:

> Included in the project distribution
>   is a collection of samples called the
>   Spring BlazeDS Integration Test Drive.
>   This samples project is set up to be
>   built with Maven and then imported
>   into Eclipse for running the
>   application via WTP.

The samples in question, must either be [spring-flex-testdrive-spring3.zip](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/samples/spring-flex-testdrive-spring3.zip) which is linked to in the document or [spring-flex-testdrive-spring3.zip](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.0.M1/samples/spring-flex-testdrive-spring3.zip) based on the notion that this is release 1.5.0.M1 (docs and samples).

After I configure maven as described with the proper environment variable:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

I then execute (per instruction) the command to install: ***mvn clean install*** from the extracted samples directory (in my case C:\spring-flex-testdrive ), I receive the following error:

```
C:\spring-flex-testdrive>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.flex.samples:spring-flex-testdrive:1.5.0.M1 (C:\spring-flex-testdrive\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.springframework.flex:spring-flex-parent:pom:1.5.0.M1 in http://maven.springframework.org/external was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
reattempted until the update interval of spring-external has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
C:\spring-flex-testdrive>
```

I have managed to get a "Spring BlazeDS" application working (with Flex), but now I'm at the point where I need to implement security, and if the samples would compile and run correctly, it'd be a huge help.  I am new to Maven, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance StackOverflow community!

Comment: Well, I've yet to figure out any additional configuration changes I need to make.  I've tried to follow along with the [sonatype / flexmojos FAQ](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/FAQ#FAQ-1.3) , but I'm not really sure where I need to "manually" install my flex/flashbuilder jars ( license.jar ?) nor what I need to change about the root **pom.xml** .  Any more thoughts?

My env. vars are: http://pastie.org/1549766

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brian, please add the following snippet to the pom.xml in the root of the samples (from where you execute mvn clean install) and re-run Maven:

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/milestone</url>
    </repository>
```

Hope that helps.

Christian

Comment: thank you so much for the help - we're getting there!  I'm quite sure the application made it through the majority of the install.  Here's my latest output from Maven: http://pastebin.com/x8XFHjej

I thought that was pretty good, so I re-ran just **mvn install** and had the following output from Maven: http://pastebin.com/nBnFGzTG

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error.  Spring Flex 1.5M2 will be out very soon.  So maybe give it another try with that.

Comment: Thanks @James Ward and @CK Lee , if nothing else, it's good to know I'm not the only one.  As soon as I work it out, I'll be sure we have all of the answers here.  I think I may need to place a license.jar file for FlexBuilder / FlashBuilder on my classpath , researching that now.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that if go with Parsley for Actionscript/Flex framework.  It is more mature in may ways than Spring-Actionscript.  Moreover it is a required library for much of Cairngorm 3.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Androider , but I was under the impression that a stack that included Java & Flex sort of assumed Spring as part of the standard implementation based on [Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_java.html) and [Spring's site](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) .

Anyone else have any thoughts on making this work?  I am new to Maven, but all of the samples seem to indicate it's pretty easy...

Comment: I thought you were talking about Spring-Actionscript.  sorry